# left to right telerik combobox in right to left mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-mvc

I'm writing a mvc 3 right to left application.
In that application I've a telerik's combobox, and I need it to be left to right.
I added a Html attribute to the combobox like that new {dir="ltr"} but it worked only for the text box  with the value but not to the list.
I also try to put the combobox within a dir="ltr" but it didn't work either.

anyone have an idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check [this example](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/combobox/rtlsupport), which shows how to use ComboBox UI component in RTL mode.

Comment: It doesn't help. It change only the textbox of the combobox but not the list of the combobox.

Comment: there is nothing to post. a simple telerik combobox inside an outer div with class t-rtl of telerik

Comment: If there is no difference between the aforementioned demo and your case, then I will suggest you open forum thread on the same matter. Without test project I will not be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a wrapper with rtl direction set, as in this demo - http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/combobox/rtlsupport? Try it.

Comment: it doesn't help. It change only the textbox of the combobox but not the list of the combobox.